# How Many Quasi-Gods Show up In Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

It seems to be a recurring theme in all versions of Star Trek, but mostly in the shows that were done while Gene Roddenberry was alive: A quasi-god shows up, seeming to be all powerful and undefeatable, and the crew of the *Enterprise* has to somehow triumph over this character.

Some examples are Gary Mitchell and Nomad from *Star Trek* (and Gary Mitchell is on the short list of possible antagonists for the next movie), Q from *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, and the Prophets from *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*.

Just how many beings are there out there with almost god-like powers in the Trek universe who seem to like to play with other intelligent life forms like humans?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Proper Star Trek*:

- Assorted Q continuum members (the Q), including Q, Q2, Quinn
- [Gorgan](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gorgan) the "Friendly Angel" [ TOS: "And the Children Shall Lead" ]
- [Beta XII-A entity, aka "(*)"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Beta_XII-A_entity) [ TOS: "Day of the Dove" ]
- The One ([Sha Ka Ree entity](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/God_%28Sha_Ka_Ree%29)) [ "*Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*" ]
- [Apollo](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Apollo) (he and the rest of Greek pantheon were aliens from Pollux IV) [ TOS: "Who Mourns for Adonais?" ]
- [Trelane (and his parents)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Trelane) [ TOS: "The Squire of Gothos" ]
- [Gary Mitchell](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gary_Mitchell), as Tango noted

Noted in HNL's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10908/84134):

- [Edo god](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Edo_God) [ TNG: "Justice" ]
- [Nacene Caretaker](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Caretaker_%28Nacene%29) [ VOY: "Caretaker", "Projections" ]

*Beings that weren't quite "god-like" as far as powers but may count*

- [Pah-wraiths](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pah_wraith) (evil version of Bajoran Prophets)
- [Bajoran Prophets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prophet) (Wormhole aliens)

*Licensed works (books, The Animated Series/TAS)*

- [Kukulkan](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kukulkan) [ TAS: "How Sharper Than a Serpent's Tooth"  ]
- The four "0" friends from [Q continuum book](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/0#0)s, which included canon's [Gorgan](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Gorgan) and [The one](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_One) (see above) and [Beta XII-A entity, aka "(*)"](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/%28*%29), as well as [0 itself](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/0) who brought all 3 into our Universe with Q's help.

Comment: @HNL - Fixed, sorry :)   +1 for yours too, especially for Edo God.

Comment: Hmm.. Does Kevin count from 'The Survivors', TNG?  (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kevin_Uxbridge) - or is he too low powered...  He's a Douwd (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd)

Comment: @Keith - He qualifies, BUT he doesn't fit the question (being pretends to be a god, and has to be overcome by Enterprise) - this one was backwards, he was pretending to be low powered and only wanted to be left alone. Feel free to add him as a separate answer or edit into one of the existing ones if you disagree

Comment: @DVK -  Well.. Kind of.. They DID have to overcome him, he just didn't combat them in quite the direct way most of the other did.. But the summoning up of an attack ship, the assault on Troi's mind and so forth..  I guess he fails on the 'Trying to pretend to be a god' / "who seem to like to play with other intelligent life forms" aspect, tho.  Ah, well. He's one of my favorites.

Comment: @DVK - there are also episodes featuring transcendent beings that evolve to god-like status by the end of the show. John Doe from 'Transfigurations' in TNG is a good example (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transfigurations_(episode)).

Comment: @DVK - Nagilum from TNG's 'Where Silence Has Lease' could also be classified as a quasi-god (http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode)).

Comment: @RobertF - do both of these fit into "god-like powers in the Trek universe who seem to like to play with other intelligent life forms like humans"?

Comment: Well, John Doe certainly interacted with humans out of compassion, don't know if he was "playing" with us. Nagilum was playing with us. :)

Comment: Does Satan count? if so there was Adra from "Devil's Due" on TNG. Although eventually they discovered the source of her powers, she did a fine job of convincing the natives and perplexing some of star fleet for a bit.

Comment: How about the Traveller, who had Q-esque powers and eventually took Wesley off the show?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Traveler never pretended to be a god, nor was antagonistic and in need of being dealy with

Comment: You left out "CharlieX" and/or the race that gave him his powers

Comment: Also left out the Metrons that make Kirk fight the Gorn.

Comment: Sylvia and Korob, the witches in Catspaw (TOS)

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with information on how many Q-continuum members there are. Most of the time, they behave as a collective entity, but as the *Voyager* episode with the civil war theme conflict in the continuum shows, there may be a whole lot of them with highly varied personalities.

Answer (score 5):

Excluding TOS:

1. Q
2. Nacene (Caretakers)
3. Founders (Shapeshifters)
4. Prophets (Wormhole aliens)
5. The [Edo God](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Edo_God) from TNG episode S01E08 (*Justice*)

There may be others posing as Gods, but they are not powerful enough to be taken seriously by anyone but their believer species.

Answer (score 3):

Nagilum, from the TNG episode "Where Silence Has Lease."

Answer (score 2):

The [Organians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_races#Organian) from "Errand of Mercy" are another example.

The Metrons from "Arena", Melkotians from "Spectre of the Gun",and Excalbians from "The Savage Curtain" may qualify, at the low end of the scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how canonical it is, but the 25th Anniversary PC game featured in one of its missions the Aztec god [Quetzalcoatl](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_25th_Anniversary_%28PC%29#5_-_.22The_Feathered_Serpent.22).

Answer (score 0):

The mysterious being from Voyager season 2 "Persistence of Vision". It's not clear what the extent of his powers are, but in this episode he controls the minds of the crew and makes himself and his ships vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Ardra's Impostor [TNG: Devil's Due]

Arridor and Kol [VOY: False Profits]

Unnamed 'Matrix' Alien [VOY: Coda] - Doesn't claim to be a god, but claims to be all-powerful over the dead.